# SQL Server 2008 Adds Namespace prefixes p1, p2, p3 etc

Tags: sql-server-2008, xquery

I'm using some XQuery in SQL Server 2008 and the results contain auto generated namespace prefixes. I am using a default namespace but don't understand why it keeps adding these.

Any ideas why this is happening or how to remove them?

Comment: Why do you care what the prefixes are, as long as they map to the correct namespace?

Comment: Can you show some code that demonstrate what you mean. Perhaps there is something to be done to name the prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you need to declare a default namespace in the xquery code as well. If not SQL auto generates position namespaces to stop conflicts.